# Grid Column ClientTemplate not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Hierarchy style Kendo grid and the inner grid doesn't seem to accept client templates. (I stripped the code irrelevant grid configuration columns out )
I really would like the client template to be something like
        `<a title="#=AlarmStatusDescription#">#=AlarmStatus#</a>`   but anytime I put anything other than a simple string in the ClientTemplate, the whole grid fails to load.

I've tried

- `.ClientTemplate("#:AlarmStatus#")`
- `.ClientTemplate("#=AlarmStatus#")`
- `.ClientTemplate("<div class="myclass"></div>")` with a separate `<script type="text/html" id="myclass">#=AlarmStatus#</script>`

  `@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AccountModel>()`

  ```
              .Name("Accounts_#=Id#")
              .Columns(columns =>
                           {

  columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Details").Click("showDetails")).Width(75);
  columns.Bound(o => o.AccountName).Width(150);                  
  columns.Bound(o => o.AlarmStatus).Width(100).ClientTemplate("#:AlarmStatus#");`

                               })
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .Model(model =>{model.Id(p => p.AccountId);})
                      .Read(read => read.Action("DetailRead", "Csr", new { personId = #=Id#" }))
                  )
                  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
                  .ToClientTemplate()
          )
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use: `.ClientTemplate("#= AlarmStatus #")`. I think that you were missing the quotes `"`.

Comment: yup your right, I think that was just a type in my posting I'll correct the post

Comment: Here's a nother little cool thing you can do .ClientTemplate("<a title=\"#=AlarmStatusDescription#\">#=AlarmStatus#</a>")

Answer (score 18):

You need to escape the sharp symbols - other way the Outer Grid will try to evaluate this **"#:AlarmStatus#"** expression. And since most probably there is no such field as AlarmStatus for the Outer Grid (it is property of the Inner one) there will be an exception. If you escape it like this the client template should be skipped by the Outer Grid, and evaluated properly by the Inner Grid.

```
.ClientTemplate("\\#= AlarmStatus \\#")
```

I hope you got the idea

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted one